# Using dictionary keys as field names in SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am writing a function to modify the table. It receives a dictionary, with keys as field names to modify and the corresponding value as the new value.

```
for key, val in kwargs.keys():
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET %s = %s WHERE user_id = %s", [key, val, user_id])
```

This approach seemed fine, but it gives a syntax error on MySQL, and that's because the field `first_name` is inserted with quotes in the query. 
So the query is like `UPDATE users SET 'first_name' = ...`

I tried all approaches to remove the quotes from the query, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how to solve this, and the reasons behind this?

Comment: I think with key names you need to do normal python string formatting ... or better yet switch to using an ORM :P

Comment: @adithya_m You need to Python string formatting for column name, SQL expressions, table_name . After that you can pass the user_given values to to your DB Library as any iterator depends on your need

Answer (score 1):

Use Python string formatting, and then pass user given values which will be handled by you DB library. **This is not prone to SQL Injection unless column name defined in your code.** If you are getting column name from user inputted values we are still prone to SQL Injection

I made one more assumption in the sample code, it seems you are updating table multiple times for given key / value pair, so I build a single query to do the same.

```
columns = kwargs.keys()
update_list = [ "%(key)s = %%(%(key)s)s" % {'key' : key} for key in columns]
kwargs.update(user_id = user_id)
cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET %(update_list)s WHERE user_id = %%(user_id)s" % { 'update_list' : ",\n".join(update_list)}, kwargs)
```

Comment: how to replace `False` with `Null` in the sql request?

Answer (score 0):

Do the string formation twice, you can still have the benefits of DB driver parameter handling:

```
for key, val in kwargs.keys():
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET %s = %%s WHERE user_id = %%s" % key, [val, user_id])
```

Comment: Or use string.format(): `cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET {} = %s WHERE user_id = %s".format(key), [val, user_id])`